# Classic ASP: Attached Debugger

Tags: debugging, asp-classic

Is it possible to step though Classic ASP VB code without Visual interdev or other such IDEs? I'm currently using Notepad++ to maintain a old ASP project and the ability to step though code at certain types would be helpful.

Thank You,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging ASP also works with Visual Studio 2005, not sure about the Express editions or other recent versions. Don't forget to activate debugging for your application in the IIS management console.

Comment: I'm long over due on marking this as the correct answer and I apologize. It turns out, it is possible and Visual Studio 2005 & 2008 both work fine.

Answer (score 3):

The only other way to step into the classic ASP code was to use script debugger that was built-into IE 5.5 (or 6). You could download it as a stand-alone solution, but you would always run it from IE "Tools" menu. You would also have to allow remote debugging of server-side code in IIS to do that.
Here's a [link](http://www.herongyang.com/asp/script_debugger.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, with VS2005 you can not use f5 to run and debug.  You must attach to the process.  I attach to the inetinfo.exe.  For some reason, this does not work and have to attach to the dllhost.exe that shows script next to it.